# Algorithm to flatten JSON arrays to rows

Tags: python, json, algorithm

I'm writing an algorithm in pure Python to do something similar to Clickhouse's [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join) function: split nested arrays into individual lines.

For example, with this input:

```json
{
    "A": "B",
    "C": [{"D": "E"}, {"F": "G"}, "H", {"D": "I"}]
}
```

I am looking to create the following output:

| A | C | C.D | C.F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | H |  |  |
| B |  | E |  |
| B |  | I |  |
| B |  |  | G |

I feel like I am almost there with this code to flatten json:

```py
def f(j, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    if isinstance(j, dict):
        for k, v in j.items():
            f(v, path+[k])

    elif isinstance(j, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(j):
            f(item, path+[i])

    else:
        print(tuple(path), j)
```

The trouble I'm running into is knowing which elements should be grouped together. For example, how can I ensure `C`, `C.D`, and `C.F` are used to split data on separate rows?

I'm looking for a pure python (or any language really) solution - not using pandas since my final code will probably not be in python. (Also: this is not homework! It's a personal project I'm working on to store JSON in Postgres and I'm trying to figure out how to do the translation!)

Comment: What if your JSON also had `"F": ["1", "2", "3"]` as an element. How would you distribute the 3 elements in F across the 4 elements in C?

Comment: The output would have 12 total elements: the original 4 based on `C` and each of those would be crossed with the 3 elements of `F`.

Comment: Can the objects be arbitrarily nested or does your example go as deep as they will?

Comment: Arbitrarily nested. (In practice they wont be terribly deep - ie, a stripe webhook - but i'm attempting to write something generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difficulty here is in trying to push state down the parse tree instead of pulling it back up.  I wrote a version that focuses on generating the correct partial representations of leaves and then at each joined point just does the correct version of join - alternation for arrays, and concatenation for objects:

```
def parse(obj, path = None):
  if path is None:
    path = []
  if isinstance(obj, list):
    return [p for i in obj  for p in parse(i, path) ]
  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    return cross_product([parse(v, path + [k]) for k, v in obj.items()])

  return [{tuple(path): obj}]

def cross_product(dicts):
  if len(dicts) == 0:
    return [{}]
  return [ {**lhs, **rhs} for lhs in dicts[0] for rhs in cross_product(dicts[1:])]
```

This will produce just the minimized rows - it won't fill in blanks.  If you need that, you can use:

```
def normalize(rows):
  keys = set([ k for r in rows for k in r ])
  for k in keys:
      for r in rows:
          if not k in r:
              r[k] = None
  return rows #optional, since we're mutating, I guess
```

To do so.